# Accepted answers  are always displayed on top?

Tags: support, answers, accepted-answer

I always thought, that the accepted answer is displayed on top of the other answers, even if the others have more votes.

This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/12488/19341) seems to be a counterexample. Why is that?

The [timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/12488/timeline) of the post indicates, that the accepted answer was given later, but that's all and should have an effect, right?

Comment: Are you ordering the questions by activity, oldest or votes?

Comment: What do you mean? So no...

Comment: You can choose how to order the answers, just above the first answer. Which one is the order you are using right now? The choice affects whether or not the accepted answer is the top one.

Comment: Ok, but clicking at a random [example](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177764/minimum-value-of-xy-when-xy-36), gives exactly what I expect: votes:1 accepted, after that votes:3, ordered by votes...

Comment: Hmm. For me all possible orderings give accepted first; however on the example linked in your question only *active* ordering gave the accepted first. Strange...

Comment: Order by activity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Normally, accepted answers are “docked” under the question. This is not true for owner accepted answers [*i.e.* when the asker accepts their own answer]; they stay in standard sort order like any other answer.

—"[Accept Your Own Answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/)" on the Stack Exchange blog, via https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=accepted+answer+top :)

Comment: Thank you very much...